# get the nearest integer

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have a file delimited by pipes.  I am not sure which bash tool would be most appropriate (I am thinking either awk or sed) to find the nearest number to those listed.

my file looks like this:

```
2|1 1 4 5
8|1 2 2 3 10 14
5|1 50 100
```

and I would like to get the output:

```
1
10
1
```

Explanation: In First Row, Nearest of 2 in {1 1 4 5} is 1. In Same way, For Second row Nearest of 8 in {1 2 2 3 10 14} is 10.For 3rd row Nearest for 5 will be 1.

Comment: Where do the 1s and 10 in your output come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[| ]' '{
  sq=($2-$1)*($2-$1);a=2;
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
    sqi=($i-$1)*($i-$1)
    if(sq<sqi){sq=sq}else{sq=sqi;a=i}                                                                                                                                                                         
  } print $a
}' file
1
10
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$ echo "$ns"
2|1 1 4 5
8|1 2 2 3 10 14
5|1 50 100
```

It is easy in Ruby:

```
$ echo "$ns" | ruby -lne 'a=$_.split(/[| \t]/)
                          a.map!{|e| Integer(e)}
                          n=a.shift
                          p a.min_by {|e| (e-n).abs}'
1
10
1
```

It could be done similarly in `gawk` by defining a customer sort function based on the first value compared the rests, sort, take the first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of doing it with `awk`:

```
awk -F"[ \t|]" '{
    n=$2;m=($1-$2)*($1-$2)
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
        d=($1-$i)*($1-$i)
        if(d<m){n=$i;m=d}
    } print n
}' input
```